# Grothendieck spectral sequence from the hypercohomology spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Is it possible to write a proof of the convergence of the  Grothendieck spectral sequence of the composition of two functors only using the convergence of the hypercohomology spectral sequences associated with the functors?  If yes, how to do so?

Comment: Dear Paul, what do you mean by "coordinate free"? And what does it mean to prove a spectral sequence? (To me that sounds as weird as saying "proving a vector space".)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal:  Sorry for the very informal language.  I have edited the question.  By "coordinate free" I meant "index free" in the sense that one writes out injective resolutions explicitly and makes a computation.  I wish to know if there is a more conceptual way of looking at it.

Comment: No need to be sorry for anything! Have you looked into derived categories? The language of derived categories provides a very elegant (albeit quite abstract) way of formulating the existence and convergence of Grothendieck's spectral sequence (among other things).

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: I haven't looked at it.  Can you give me a good reference in general for derived categories and for the formulation of the Grothendieck spectral sequence?

Comment: I would recommend Hartshorne's chapter on derived categories in the volume "Residues and duality".

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I think derived categories are the wrong way to go here. Derived functors can be composed directly. It is hard to extract anything useful from that.